# How can I use this API in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, rest

I want to use this API as a Web module in Azure Data Factory
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory

But it required me to get a bearer Token first in Authorization.
[image]

I'm try to set up a token request first in this link but no help. Any guidance is appreciated
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the bearer token manually, you can use the `MSI` Authentication in your screenshot directly.

Navigate to your subscription or ADFv2 in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for the name of your ADFv2 and add it as an `Owner/Contributor` role in the subscription. Then the MSI of your ADFv2 will be able to call the rest api.

[image]

**Update**:

Add the MSI like below, for exampple, my ADFv2 named `joyfactory`, just add the MSI with the same name as an `Owner` or `Contributor`.

[image]

After adding it, check it in the `Role assignments` , it should be like below.

[image]

Comment: @TonyAnderson Have you added the MSI as Owner or Contributor role? And what this `I loggin to ADFv2 using the same ID, password that I used to created it ` mean?

Comment: @TonyAnderson No, it is not correct. You need to add the [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity) of your ADFv2, not your user account. Just click the Add role assignment, search for your ADFv2 name, in your case, it is `VTA-ADF-dev`, then add it as Owner or Contributor.

Comment: @TonyAnderson It looks like the result has been returned, `"vaule" : []`, there is no result via your query.