# How to call a REST API using Azure Data Factory Pipelines?

Tags: azure, rest, api, oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory

I would like to execute a REST API with oauth authentication using ADF Pipeline. Without oauth2, I could call any REST APIs. So here my question is, does this ADF pipeline support REST APis with oauth2 authentication ? if yes. Please provide a solution

The API which is am trying, you can find from this URL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory

Thanks
Binu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call the REST API with a [`Web activity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) in the pipeline, select the Authentication with `MSI` in the web activity.

[image]

Navigate to your subscription or ADFv2 in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for the name of your ADFv2 and add it as an `Owner/Contributor` role in the subscription. Then the MSI of your ADFv2 will be able to call the rest api.

For exampple, my ADFv2 named `joyfactory`, just add the MSI with the same name as an `Owner` or `Contributor`.

[image]

After adding it, check it in the `Role assignments` , it should be like below.

[image]

For more details, check this [**similar issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317140/how-can-i-use-this-api-in-azure-data-factory/58317404#58317404).